# Strategy for removing english "crap" words from string NLP such as "um", "uh"

Tags: python, nlp

Is there a good python library that specifically contains some kind of dictionary of common english "throw away words" such as "um", "uh" that I could use to clean up text for NLP?

Similarly, my colleague started making a list of slang/off words.  I'd love a python library that finds all of these.  His js code below does stuff like turn "nope" and "naw" into "no"

```
  txt = txt.replace(
        /\b(yeah|ya|yep|yup|yes)\b/g, "yes"
    ).replace(
        /\b(no|naw|nope)\b/g, "no"
    ).replace(
        /\b([ah]+|uh-huh|uh+|um+|mhm+|huh+|oh)\b/g, ""
    ).replace(
        /\b(im|i'm|i am)\b/g, "im"
    ).replace(
        /\b(gotta|gonna|got to|going to|wanna|want to)\b/g, "yyxxa"
    ).replace(
        /\b(ok|okay|k)\b/g, "okay"
    );
```

Comment: I do not believe that which you are requesting exists.  Maybe you could make a list or text file that you could incorporate into your program.

Answer (score 0):

A piece of an answer is here: https://github.com/words/fillers/blob/master/index.json

Comment: Please update the link.